# Problems with lining stuff up

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

http://dalexl.webs.com/newboxA.htm

http://dalexl.webs.com/newboxB.htm

I have the two pages, newboxA and newboxB.  They are both the same page with only one difference, a single space.

There is no difference in Google Chrome, but newboxA doesn't connect the lines (because of the space between the elements) and newboxB renders all crazy and incorrectly.

There is one space difference between the two.  newboxB doesn't have this space. newboxA does.  I'm using the span with the text "TEST" so that I can but the header links on top of my banner image (which is made up of three different images for the blinking lamp effect).

Google Chrome displays the page fine either way (with or without the space), why not IE?

**BTW**

I'm viewing this with IE7.  I can't upgrade or change my focus (for browsers) because this is a school assignment and my teacher will be viewing the page with just IE.

I prefer the final copy to work in both IE and Google Chrome, but just IE is fine too (if required).  I will base the "answer" on this factor (if it comes to it).

CSS Link:
http://dalexl.webs.com/css/default.css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a doctype to the page. This should fix the issue for you. Here a [quick explanation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp)

Easiest doctype puts page into html 5 but should be fine for your purposes. It is: `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`

This should be the first thing in your html.

HTH :)